# Windows Server bandwidth limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, server, windows-server

How can I find bandwidth limit and "packets per second" limit for Windows Server 2012 hosted on Google Cloud? I experience some issues when there're to much clients on my server but I can't find any limitations? Server is written on C# using sockets and TCP connection.

Comment: Google does not publish bandwidth limits nor packets per second limitations. Google does specify network bandwidth up to 2 Gbit per core. You will not achieve these numbers in the real world except in testing. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/5-steps-to-better-gcp-network-performance

Comment: Please provide more information about your use case, issues and expectations.